# Thread that bind()s when terminated does not unbind the UDP listen port number

Tags: linux

A Google shows that this seems to be a common question with no good answers however I thought I'd ask and maybe someone knows a way to resolve what appears to be a common issue.

When a thread is launched and it performs a bind(), after the thread is completed and terminates, the UDP port number that was bind()ed is still being held as in use, if another thread is launched, the bind() to the port number fails.

The process which launched that thread appears to retain ownership of the UDP port that was bind()ed and merely terminating the thread doesn't release it.

Question: Is there a way to release the bind()ed UDP port number when the thread that asked for it terminates?

Thanks!

Comment: Why exactly doesn't your thread close the socket descriptor it opened for that port? This should free the port and all related kernel resources...

Answer (score 0):

File descriptors, including sockets, are allocated to the process, not to a specific thread.  If you don't perform a `close` on the socket, it will be freed when the process terminates.

Please ensure that your thread performs `close` on the offending socket before it terminates.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, in fact pthread_create() launches my thread, I enter in to a while() loop and when I want to terminate the thread, a flag allows the while() to exit, I perform clean-up which includes a shutdown() and a fclose() on the socket that has the bind() however as was noted, the process owns the bind() not the thread, so the bind() remains.

What I believe I'll do is rather than terminate the thread I'll do a pthread_suspend() and if I need it again I'll do a pthread_resume(), that way the thread always live and the bind() is only ever done once while the process is running.

Thanks!